# Tableau does not import all records from data source (.txt)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple text file as a data source of customer names with three columns.  'Refresh All Extracts' do not include certain blocks of customers.  For example, the key to the table is a state/customer.  In the data source tab, this table omits specific states, not just random records.   It's repeatable, but can't understand why a state here or there would be omitted in the Data Source.

EDIT:

I turned on Data Interpreter.  It tells me data has been excluded, but the data source tab with my table doesn't have any records marked with *** DATA REMOVED ***.  If it did, would I expect to see a reason why?

[image]

Comment: One easy quick test is to check whether you get the same behavior if you disable the extract

Comment: How do you mean 'disable extract'?  Change it to Live?

Comment: You can right click on a data source to see a context menu, or use the data menu from the top of the window, to see menu options for extracts - such as refresh, properties etc. One command lets you temporarily disable an extract, to query the original source as you would in a live connection. That’s a good way too see if the behavior you are seeing is somehow related to using an extract.

Comment: In many/most cases, using an extract will just impact performance, not behavior. But there are circumstances where the behavior differs - such as when aggregating in an extract or using functions not available in the original source

Comment: The table is a customer table with three columns (site, cust_no, cust_name).  As simple as it gets. It has 840,000 records.  Tableau imports about half of it.  But, it is a specific set of records--not a random set.  It's always the same records that get dropped.  There is nothing in the original text file that suggests a problem with these records.  There are no filters.   Baffling.  Doesn't matter if it's Live or Extract

Comment: Sounds like a possible driver bug to report to Tableau support, but there is one more easy thing to check. Make sure you don’t have any data source filters defined (they aren’t always easy to see) To see, go to the data source tab and click the word filters at the top right.

Comment: Also worth checking whether tableau is correctly identifying the *type* of the column. If it recognises customer numbers, for example, as a numeric field but some numbers halfway down the table contain non-numeric characters, it might choke on those. If in doubt force everything to *string* and see if the results are different.

Comment: Just converted numbers to string.  Same result.  Makes me doubt all the other extracts now. Hmmmm.   No filters exist.

Comment: I tried using Data Interpreter.  It says it removed some data, but have no idea why, or where to see it.   The tab with the data file shows no problems.